# How can I connect an Android HTML/JS program to a LAN server?

Tags: javascript, android, html, node.js, socket.io

Note: relatively new to websockets and communication in general, so please give overall advice as well!

I've been working on a LAN chat app with HTML/JS/CSS and wanted to port it over to Android (already working on PC). My first intuition was open the HTML file the same way I do on my computer - namely, save to the SD card and open it with a file explorer. When I open up the application on my computer, the server authorizes handshake and proceeds with getting and receiving info; when I open it on my phone, the server authorizes the handshake...and thats it. There is no response after that from the phone. I have a feeling I'm missing something fundamental about how Android handles the software, but I have no idea what...

I boiled everything down to a simple LAN communication with the server.

On a PC, the code below outputs "Hello: " on the server side. On an android, nothing.

HTML :

```
    <!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script src="http://192.168.1.112:4000/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />

</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scriptsTeacher.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Javascript Client:

```
(function(){    
    var App;

  App = {};

  //sends connection event
  App.socket = io.connect('192.168.1.112:4000');

  App.init = function() 
  { 
      App.socket.emit('hello', { });
  }

  $(function() {
    return App.init();
  });
}).call(this);
```

Javascript Server:

```
(function() {
  var io;
  io = require('socket.io').listen(4000, "0.0.0.0"); 
  io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) 
  { 
      socket.on('hello', function(data)
      {
          process.stdout.write("hello: ");
      });

  });
}).call(this);
```

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: Is your Android phone connected with your wifi?

Comment: Yea. If its not, the html file won't load locally. When it's connected to wifi, the file loads fine but there isn't any communication; talking to yourself just isn't as fun...

Comment: Well above you wrote that your html file is located on your sd card. If you are able to open that file via network like http://192.168.1.112:4000/ it should work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please make sure that your mobile is connected with your WiFi, so your phone should be able to connect to your server. If not use a ddns like dyndns.org (well not best choice today) and setup a port forwarding for all relevant ports.

Also remember to open your html file via http. It is possible that network communication with websockets are disabled for security reasons.

That should fix your problem.

Comment: The phone is definitely connected to wifi, and can connect to the server - like I said, the server does authorize a handshake, so there is initial communication...it just stops. I actually agree that its likely a security thing; what do you mean exactly by open the html file via http?

Comment: The url in the browser must start with http:// and not file://. That is something about the same origin policy. But for the file scheme are some more restrictions